# Notice thrown when creating numeric pagination on custom query

Tags: wp-query, pagination, query, errors

I've been working with a custom query with numeric pagination (i.e. < 1 2 3 4 >). I've got it working the way I would expect, however, it keeps throwing this error:

*Notice: Use of undefined constant custom_pagination - assumed 'custom_pagination' in /websitepath/wp-content/plugins/portgallery/galleryTemplate.php on line 129.*

Line 129 is this: 
**if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {**

I have no idea how to fix this problem, and can't seem to find much help in the Codex or when Googled. I'm sure I'm just missing something stupid. Help?

```
<?php
function custom_pagination($numpages = '', $pagerange = '', $paged = '') {

    if (empty($pagerange)) {
    $pagerange = 2;
    }

    global $paged;
    if (empty($paged)) {
    $paged = 1;
    }
    if ($numpages == '') {
    global $wp_query;
    $numpages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
    if (!$numpages) {
        $numpages = 1;
    }
    }

    $pagination_args = array(
    'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
    'format' => 'page/%#%',
    'total' => $numpages,
    'current' => $paged,
    'show_all' => False,
    'end_size' => 1,
    'mid_size' => $pagerange,
    'prev_next' => True,
    'prev_text' => __('&laquo;'),
    'next_text' => __('&raquo;'),
    'type' => 'plain',
    'add_args' => false,
    'add_fragment' => ''
    );

    $paginate_links = paginate_links($pagination_args);

    if ($paginate_links) {
    echo "<nav class='custom-pagination'>";
    echo "<span class='page-numbers page-num'>Page " . $paged . " of " . $numpages . "</span> ";
    echo $paginate_links;
    echo "</nav>";
    }
}
?>

<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var('page') ) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;

$query_args = array(
    'taxonomy' => 'portfolio_categories',
    'term' => 'artwork',
    'post_type' => 'portfolio',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'paged' => $paged
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($query_args);
?>

<?php if ($the_query->have_posts()) : ?>

    <?php while ($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
    <article class="loop">
        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
        <div class="content">
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
        </div>
    </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php
    if (function_exists(custom_pagination)) {
    custom_pagination($the_query->max_num_pages, "", $paged);
    }
    ?>

    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've already done all of the heavy lifting. [`function_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php) expects a string for the first parameter, so `custom_pagination` should be `'custom_pagination'` (add quotes):

```
if ( function_exists( 'custom_pagination' ) ) { ...
```

Comment: Oh crap. Figured it'd be that simple. Now I'm feeling stupid. It certainly took away the error. Sorry, and thank you so much for catching my error.

Comment: Happy to help! Maybe this will help someone in the future with a similar issue. [I ran into pretty much the same thing in Sass before.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396956/global-variable-exists-is-triggering-errors-in-sass).

Comment: Extremely glad to know it's not just me! Thanks again!